# read all php file inside folder using include function

Tags: php

I try to read all files inside of my folder. I create one folder **sample**, inside in sample folder I create php file **testing.php**. This file look like this **sample/testing.php**.

I create another file outside of sample folder. I name it **details.php**

I put these codes inside of my **details.php**

```
function include_all_php($folder){

    foreach (glob("{$folder}/*.php") as $filename)
    {
        echo $filename;
        include($filename);
    }
}
$file =  __DIR__."/sample";
include_all_php($file);

showx();
```

and inside of my **testing.php** file I put these codes

```
function showx(){
    echo "heroo";
}
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function shox()
```

I echo the $filename. It shows my file testing.php but why is it I cannot call the function showx()? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: You are saying you created file as **sample/testing.php** and you are using `sample1` as folder name.

Comment: sorry I already update it.

Comment: Is it as simple as ... You call the function `function showx()` but you called `shox()`... Simple typo! _Error messages are there to be read and understood_

Comment: whilst what youre doing is ok.. you probably should have a read of [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).  Yes it uses Object oriented PHP, but you probably should be as well anyway.  If this is new, then its far better to learn PHP this way from scratch.

Comment: sorry guys. Programmer error. my bad. @RiggsFolly thank you, You have an eye of an eagle. I get it now.

Comment: I will delete this post. sorry for your time

Comment: FYI, functions defined inside other functions (as in your case) belong to global scope so will work just fine but you won't be able to use variables defined in your included files. It can be a pro or a con.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this before:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== false);
}

function include_all_php($folder){
$dir = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder));
    foreach ($dir as $filename)
    {
        if(endsWith($filename, ".php")){
            include $filename;
        }
    }
}

include_all_php('/path/');
```